# Error C2061 In visual studio

Tags: c++

I try to reference a struct from another class in my code and it gives me an error, saying I have a syntax problem.

```
#pragma once

#include "Definitions.h"

#include "GV.h"
#include "UI.h"
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Item.h"

class Figure {
public:
    //Figure index
    struct FIGURE_TYPE {
        //Where to crop the image from
        SDL_Rect crop;
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    //The game figure
    FIGURE_TYPE figure_index[FIGURE_COUNT];

    //The figure array
    int figure_array[MAP_HEIGHT / 64][MAP_WIDTH / 64];

    //Functions
    Figure ( void );
    bool draw_figures ( SDL_Surface* screen, SDL_Surface* figures, SDL_Rect camera, Figure::FIGURE_TYPE figure_spec[FIGURE_COUNT] );
};
```

That's the struct in Figure.h,

```
#pragma once

#include "Definitions.h"

#include "GV.h"
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Figure.h"

class UI {
public:
    UI ( void );
    void set_camera ( SDL_Rect& camera, Figure::FIGURE_TYPE figure_spec[FIGURE_COUNT] );
    bool draw_map ( SDL_Surface* screen, SDL_Rect& camera, SDL_Surface* tiles, SDL_Surface* figures, Figure::FIGURE_TYPE figure_spec[FIGURE_COUNT] );
    bool draw_status ( void );
};
```

And that is where I reference it, from another header file called UI.h. I know there is a problem with referencing structures, I just don't know how to fix it. Simple problem, any one wanna help?

The problem **is not** that Figure Type is declared outside of Figure.h, or that it is private as opposed to public.

## Error Reports

> Error 1   error C2653: 'Figure' : is not a class or namespace name    c:\users\jim\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\ui.h 13  1   roguelike
>
> Error 3   error C2653: 'Figure' : is not a class or namespace name    c:\users\jim\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\ui.h 14  1   roguelike
>
> Error 2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FIGURE_TYPE'    c:\users\jim\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\ui.h 13  1   roguelike
>
> Error 4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FIGURE_TYPE'    c:\users\jim\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\ui.h 14  1   roguelike

Comment: What do you think `Figure::` is doing? Do you think `Figure` is a namespace? A type? Or something else? (It's hard to correct your misunderstanding when I don't know what your reasoning is.)

Comment: I'm sorry, Figure.h contains a class declaration called Figure. I thought that Figure:: was a way to reference it.

Comment: Please include the entire error message.  That message is an explanation of what's wrong and where.

Comment: I've added all of the code you should need and the error reports.

Comment: @user2014289: Well there's your problem. I'm not sure why you thought that, but it's 100% false. Only a namespace or a class type goes before `::`. (Hence the error message.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: `Figure` is a class type. You're wrong. **The OP's syntax and understanding is 100% correct.**

Comment: What should be used as opposed to `::`?

Comment: @JimHurley: The correct answer is given below.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: The question has changed. *Now* Figure is a class type. It's still hard to tell if his understanding is correct. It's not clear if he thinks he should use `Figure::` because that's the name of the class or because that's the name of the header file.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: `Figure.h contains a class declaration called Figure` 13 mins ago, second comment. I am satisfied that the OP understands his code.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: Unfortunately, they're needed to understand context that's still relevant, and SO won't let me edit them. I'll have to let the later comments clarify the earlier ones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a circular dependency: UI.h depends on Figure.h, and Figure.h depends on UI.h.  You need to break the circular dependency by removing the `#include` of one file in the other.  In this case, since I don't see anything in Figure.h using anything in UI.h, you should just remove the `#include "UI.h"` from Figure.h and be all set.

Comment: +1 as your solution is more specific -- I didn't spot that the dependency isn't even required

Comment: Thank you! I have more questions about forward dependency, but I will just start a new thread as they aren't relevant to this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is fine.

What is not fine is that you have a circular dependency between your headers, and this is breaking your `#include`s.

In this case, it's leading to `Figure` not being visible from within "UI.h"; even though your syntax is correct, this causes the errors you've seen because "UI.h" doesn't *know* that your syntax is correct, because it doesn't know what `Figure` is.

Do not have circular dependencies. Use [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) where possible to help you.